# Build for Git Virtual File System

Tags: git

I think Microsoft designed a driver that will keep track of what files are needed during the writing process to get those files from the remote git server.

As Git Virtual File System is designed for larger repos, how does it handle the builds because shouldn't we download the whole repo for the build?

How has this been handled?

Answer (score 1):

You may not need an entire repository for any given build.

For example, many resources may be only applicable to a certain build configuration, or there may be documentation that isn't needed to build the product.

For those files that *are* needed for your build, they will be retrieved on demand. There's no way around that.

The benefit of VFS for Git is that you didn't need to retrieve all those files first, say if you only wanted to work on some code in a few files and did not need to build the whole thing. For enterprise-level projects such as Microsoft Windows, you're not going to be doing full builds very often.